# Adding username when submitting form on django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, model

I am trying to store the username of the user currently logged in when they submit information on a form on a django website.

This is what my models.py file looks like so far:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Transfer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = User._meta.get_field('username')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
```

however this doesn't seem to work. The migrations etc work fine and the server runs, but when I submit information on the form I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: transfer_transfer.username
```

Any advice on how I could get the username to save would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That declaration doesn't make any sense in a model definition. It might "work", in the sense that you get a field with the same properties as User.username, but it isn't doing anything useful; you could just as well define it directly as `models.CharField`.

Instead you need to define a ForeignKey from Transfer to User, and call it `user`; there is plenty of documentation on how to do this, and also plenty of questions here on how to fill in the user field automatically on form submission.